# SQL Server query optimization using indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, performance

I have been reading some articles on query optimization. All articles mention `indexing` as another technique for query optimization. But at the end of a section on indexing, there will be a statement discouraging the use of indexes on an operational database. There will be a statement similar to the one below:

> Every time a write is made to the database, the indexes are unusable until they have updated. If the database is constantly receiving writes then the indexes will never be usable. This is why indexes are typically applied to databases in data warehouses that get new data updated on a scheduled basis(off-peak hours) and not production databases which might be receiving new writes all the time.

My question is, how do I calculate the acceptable rate of write for indexes to be useful on an operational database?

I have not found a resource that can guide me on how to make this determination.

Comment: SQL Server or Postgres?

Comment: I'm pretty sure such a statement isn't found anywhere in the SQL Server documentation, at least. Indexes are updated synchronously with data changes, so it is simply not true there that indexes would be unusable with constant writes. They just slow down writes, but the trade-off for speeding up reads typically makes this more than worth it. There is not much point to an "operational database" that can't service read requests effectively because there are no indexes...

Comment: Four letter word: Test.

Comment: I assume [this](https://dataschool.com/sql-optimization/how-indexing-works/) is the quoted source. Though the same quote appears [here](https://quick-adviser.com/when-is-it-not-to-use-indexes-in-a-database/), [here](https://medium.com/geekculture/indexing-in-postgres-db-4cf502ce1b4e) and possibly [here](https://www.coursehero.com/tutors-problems/MYSQL/32993150-Idea-3-Indexing-for-Different-Query-Types-There-are-many-types-of/#answer-86893518)... Don't you love plagiarism?

Comment: @Larnu: looks like it. They are wrong again at the end with "Every table with a primary key has one clustered index".

Comment: This is why projects have documentation [Indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html). So you don't have to read random nonsense off the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Try "reorganize" index instead of "rebuild" index. Reorganizing an index does not lock the tables. [According to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=To%20reorganize%20all%20indexes%20in%20a%20table%201,Indexes%20to%20be%20reorganized%20...%20More%20items%20):

> …long-term object-level locks are not held and queries or updates to the underlying table can continue during the `ALTER INDEX ... REORGANIZE` operation.